# Question to the width parameter: Website (via tumblr) is not on 100% on mobile devices

Tags: css, html, mobile, tumblr

This tumblr ([johannesjakobi.tk](http://www.johannesjakobi.tk/)) that I use as a website, works good on desktop-webbrowsers but on mobile devices the main elements do not have the desired wide range (of filling out the screen by ideally 95%). Is it a problem with any "width"-parameter?

This is how it looks on mobile [google-](https://i.ibb.co/bL4b9Cx/thumbnail3.jpg) and [safari-](https://i.ibb.co/LtHXPyh/thumbnail4.jpg)browser.

Thank you a lot for your knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is your navigation. The images seem to be resizing to the viewport width.

For the navigation, I would either implement this:

```
#top nav a {
      display: inline-block;
}
```

Or if you just want it for a particular media query snap point:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
   #top nav a {
      display: inline-block;
   }
}
```

Or you can change the `display` property to `block`. This will create each anchor as a block element with 100% width. I've also added text align left (I would only implement this for mobile, as otherwise it would stack your navigation on top of each other which makes much less sense on desktop).

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    #top nav a {
       display: block;
       text-align: left;
    }
}
```

See attached images for reference.

[image: display inline-block]

[image: display block]

Comment: Thank you a lot, lharby! I will try that next week! Sadly I can not vote yet. But your comment seems to be helpful!